# Asm to C++ with DLL Injection

Tags: c++, assembly, dll, code-injection

I made a console to test for IsDebuggerPresent and i am trying to change its output.
Memory region before DLL was injected : http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/842/hso7.jpg/
Memory region after DLL was injected : http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/59/i1jw.jpg/

I wish to change the address at 004116D5(selected gray address) from JE 004116DE to JNZ/JNE 004116DE using C++.

```
DWORD asmAddy = 0x004116D5;    
#define Naked __declspec(naked)
Naked void changeasm()
{
_asm
{
jnz 0x004116DE
}
}
```

under DllMain , i used Microsoft Detours 1.5

```
DetourFunction((PBYTE)asmAddy,(PBYTE)changeasm);
```

in the after image, it seems like it jumps to a memory of the injected dll.Can someone help me with this?I have changed the opcode using OllyDbg and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think Detours will replace an entire function by hooking the import table, won't it? That doesn't sound like what you are really trying to do.

If I undersand your question, you want to change an opcode from JE (0x74) to JNE (0x75). Writing to a code area is protected. You need to change the protected of the memory before you can write the new opcode to the known location. Something like this (untested code without error handling):

```
char *address = 0x004116d5;
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
VirtualQuery(address, &mbi, sizeof(mbi));
VirtualProtect(mbi.BaseAddress, mbi.RegionSize, PAGE_READWRITE, &mbi.Protect);

*address = 0x75; // opcode of 

// restore the memory protection
DWORD oldProtect;
VirtualProtect(mbi.BaseAddress, mbi.RegionSize, mbi_thunk.Protect, &oldProtect);
```

Note, though, that this is all very risky. If this is an address in a DLL, then the DLL may be relocated and the address will be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have found using google that Detours work by placing a jmp in the address that i wish to hook , hence there was a jmp and not jnz/jne in the after image, and then the address that it jumps to is my function(explaining why it was a address within the injected dll) . However, my goal is to do like what you said,but not writing to the memory bytes but changing it directly using asm.

Comment: The adress is already assigned.
You can only change it, if You try to write to protected memory.
And asm will not be "the special solution" in here, as You might think.

Comment: cdmh mentions that the address may change if modifying a dll. Though this is true to an extent, you can and probably should use EnumerateProcessModules to find the modules base address of the code you are writing to. This will also avoid ASLR issues.